# Fixed-length HOG descriptor for variable sized images

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, feature-detection, scikit-image

I'm working on some object detection code, however my objects don't have a fixed size, so;

```
skimage.feature.hog(obj)
```

doesn't give me equal length vectors(since it uses fixed sized cells), and therefore I can't use learning algorithms on them.

So, I tried dynamically assigning HOG feature length:

```
from __future__ import division

def describe_object(obj, div=8):
    width, height = obj.shape
    f = skimage.feature.hog(obj, normalise=True,
                            pixels_per_cell=(height//div, width//div))
    return f
```

But, now it *mostly* gives `2916` sized vectors, but sometimes it gives longer vectors (like `3402` elements long) too.

I believe this happens when some specific ratio between bin size and object's shape, but don't know why exactly.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you scaled the image, you would lose image aspect ratio and other features. So scaling is not a good idea.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could scale the images to a fixed size, before calculating the HOG features.